# Input fields disabled in teams App while debugging locally and invalid client Id error in console

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am working on teams app with create tab functionality.
While debugging and running the app locally, the app is loading but I am unable to interact with any of the user editable fields
like input box, dropdown etc.

On inspecting I can see an error that the clientId is invalid when Graph api trying to login and get content. Below is the error

> Uncaught ErrorWithCode.InvalidConfiguration: clientId in configuration is invalid: undefined.
> at TeamsUserCredential.loadAndValidateConfig (https://localhost:53000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:113083:11)

I have clientId mentioned in the .fx/states/state.dev.json file under

```
 "fx-resource-aad-app-for-teams": {
    "clientId": "XXXX",
```

It tries to get data but from Graph API using below code.

```
credentials = new TeamsUserCredential();
if (!_graph) _graph = createMicrosoftGraphClient(credentials, SCOPE);
return _graph.api(url);
```

ClientId that we have provided is a valid and has not reached its expiry yet. Even we created new key but issue is same.

Note : Fields are editable when I launch the app using Remote option
Any ideas on how can I resolve this?

Comment: Show your code. These are most likely two different errors. Your clientid is undefined.

Comment: @tauzN - Added code for clientId and error screenshot